# Concatenating two possibly null strings with a separator

Tags: c#

I have two strings (`aggregatePath` and `pathFromParent`), either of which might be `null` or an empty string. I want to concatenate the two strings with a separator only if neither is `null` or empty. This is what I've ended up with:

```csharp
FullPath =
    aggregatePath +
    aggregatePath is not (null or "") && pathFromParent is not (null or "") ? "." : "" +
    pathFromParent;
```

but it seems overly complex for what I'm trying to do.

**How can I better clarify the intent of this code?**

I'm not asking about performance. I've just come back to this code after a while, and it took me a few moments to figure out the intent. Is there perhaps some better idiom for this?

Using C# 9.

Comment: `string.Join(".", paths.Where(x => x != null))` where `paths = new List<string>{aggregatePath , pathFromParent}`.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I was thinking to use an array, but it still doesn't feel clear -- why am I creating this new instance of array/`List<string>`? (NB. I'm checking for both `null` and `""`.)

Comment: If you want more clarity why not simply write things down explicitly, e.g  `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(first) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(second))  { seperator = string.Empty }`. You can use `string.Join (separator, first, second)` afterwards.

Comment: `FullPath = $"{aggregatePath}{(aggregatePath?.Length > 0 && pathFromParent?.Length > 0 ? "." : "")}{pathFromParent}";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to clarify your intention is to write down things explicitly.

Start by setting the separator to `.` by default.

```
string separator = ".";
```

Then, use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to check whether one of the two strings is either `null` or `string.Empty` and set the `separator` to `string.Empty` if that's the case.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(aggregatePath) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(pathFromParent)) {
    separator = string.Empty;
}
```

Lastly, join the two string using `string.Join`.

```
string.Join (separator, aggregatePath, pathFromParent);
```

Might not be that fancy but it's quite easy to understand.

[Try it out yourself.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dB57yX)

Comment: My subjective feeling about this is that pulling out the `separator` into a separate variable is both clear and concise. But I'll accept your answer because it does answer the question.